# Characterize all primes p such that 15 is a square modulo p

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I was having some difficulty understanding the following parts of this proof:

Proof:

Obviously, 15 is a square mod 2, 3, 5. So suppose p > 5. We compute the Jacobi
symbol:
($\frac{15}{p}$) = ($\frac{3}{p})(\frac{5}{p}$) = $(-1)^\frac{p-1}{2}(\frac{p}{3})(\frac{p}{5}) $

Up to here, all is fine, but now is where I got confused:

"So the answer will depend on p modulo 4 · 15 = 60. Looking at the φ(60) = 2 · 2 · 4 = 16
residue classes mod 60, we see that the RHS is +1 exactly when

$p  \equiv    \pm1   , \pm7  ,  \pm 11,   \pm17 \pmod{60}$ "

I have absolutely no clue why we are working mod 60 nor how they obtained the above numbers.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: When you say "up to here, all is fine", you are incorrect. There is an error on the previous line. Your computation of the symbol is incorrect. The factor of $(-1)^{p-1}$ is wrong (and always equal to $1$, since $p$ is odd). By Quadratic reciprocity, if $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ then you don't get a sign change, and if $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$ then you get a sign change from inverting$\left(\frac{3}{p}\right)$.

Comment: So that should be a factor of $(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$ instead.

Comment: Sorry yes, I made a mistake it should have a factor of 2, I've edited it.

Comment: Well, so what do you need? If $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, either $p$ is a square mod 3 and mod 5, or is not a square mod 3 nor mod 5. That gives you congruences modulo 3, 4, and 5 that $p$ must satisfy, which by the Chinese Remainder Theorem, will be equivalent to a single congruence modulo $(3)(4)(5)=60$. That's where the modulo 60 comes from. Consider all combinations that yield $1$.

Comment: Thank you I finally got it, it seemed that having it written as (3)(4)(5) definitely makes clearer the use of the Chinese-Remainder-Theorem.

Comment: @DiegoVera You should now either answer your own question and accept your answer or delete it. Otherwise it stays on the unanswered queue.

Answer (score -1):

This is a fairly standard exercise. As you note, using the Legendre (or Jacobi) symbol and Quadratic Reciprocity, we have
$$\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{15}{p}\right) &= \left(\frac{3}{p}\right)\left(\frac{5}{p}\right)\\
&=(-1)^{(\frac{p-1}{2})(\frac{3-1}{2})}\left(\frac{p}{3}\right)(-1)^{(\frac{p-1}{2})(\frac{5-1}{2})}\left(\frac{p}{5}\right)\\
&= (-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\left(\frac{p}{3}\right)\left(\frac{p}{5}\right).
\end{align*}$$

So we have a number of cases. Excluding $2$, $3$, and $5$ (for which $15$ is a square), we have:

1. If $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, then for $15$ to be a square modulo $p$ we need $\left(\frac{p}{3}\right)=\left(\frac{5}{p}\right)$. That means either $p\equiv 1\pmod{3}$ and $p\equiv \pm 1\pmod{5}$; or $p\equiv 2\pmod{3}$ and $p\equiv \pm2\pmod{5}$. Using the Chinese Remainder Theorem for the three congruences, we get: if $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, $p\equiv1 \pmod{3}$, and $p\equiv 1\pmod{5}$, then $p\equiv 1\pmod{60}$. If $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, $p\equiv 1\pmod{3}$, and $p\equiv 4\pmod{5}$, then $p\equiv 49\equiv -11\pmod{60}$. Etc. We end up with
   $$p\equiv 1,\ -11,\ 17,\  -7\pmod{60}.$$
2. If $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$, then we need $\left(\frac{p}{3}\right)=-\left(\frac{p}{5}\right)$, so either $p\equiv 1\pmod{3}$ and $p\equiv \pm 2\pmod{5}$, or else $p\equiv 2\pmod{3}$ and $p\equiv \pm1\pmod{5}$. These give the other four values modulo $60$:
   $$p\equiv 7,\ -17, 11,\ -1\pmod{60}.$$

So this gives that the primes for which $15$ is a square are precisely $p=2$, $3$, $5$, and all primes $p$ such that $p\equiv \pm 1,\ \pm7,\ \pm 11,\ \pm 17\pmod{60}$, as claimed.